# django filling database data migration fails

Tags: python, django, migration

I got following migration in django:

```
# Generated by Django 2.2.12 on 2020-05-20 16:22
from django.db import migrations
import re


def numeric_version(version):
    digits = 4
    pattern = r"(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)"
    major, minor, patch = tuple(map(int, re.findall(pattern, version)[0]))
    return patch + pow(10, digits) * minor + pow(10, 2 * digits) * major


def insert_numeric_software_version(apps, scheme_editor):
    Device = apps.get_model("devices", "Device")
    for device in Device.objects.all():
        if device.software_version is not None:
            device.numeric_software_version = numeric_version(device.software_version)


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ("devices", "0037_device_numeric_software_version"),
    ]

    operations = [insert_numeric_software_version]
```

It should fill the "numeric_software_version" field in the database with numeric fields.
In the model this field is:

```
numeric_software_version = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

When I run "`python manage.py migrate`" I got following error:

```
 File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 234, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 114, in apply
    operation.state_forwards(self.app_label, project_state)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'state_forwards'
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.. I checked my numeric_version number apart from the migration and that should work. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/migration-operations/#runpython) i guess you should change:

```
operations = [insert_numeric_software_version]
```

to:

```
operations = [migrations.RunPython(insert_numeric_software_version)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This error also occurs when declaring a second operation in the list instead of the tuple.
eg mistakenly using this

```
    class Migration(migrations.Migration):
        dependencies = [('app', '0001_initial'),]
        operations = [migrations.RunPython(load_fixture), clear_fixture_files]
```

Instead of

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
        dependencies = [('app', '0001_initial'),]
        operations = [migrations.RunPython(load_fixture, clear_fixture_files),]
```